# How to protect a directory and/or certain files in an extremely secure manner?

Tags: php, security

I'm starting have a directory full of PHP files that I need to protect from unauthorized access. It would pretty much be the end of the world for me if someone unauthorized was somehow able to gain access to these files. One thing that I should note, however, is that other files on my website need to include some of these PHP files in order to function correctly.

What would be the best way to secure these files? I have read about using a .htaccess file to password protect a directory, but I'm wondering if that's really the best and most secure way?

Thank you!

Comment: Just store them outside the web root... there is a lot more to building a secure system though.

Comment: Are they supposed to be web accessible by you, or not web accessible at all? If not at all, store them outside your document root

Comment: @Michael - Some of the files need to be accessible to pages on my website (several files are just full of functions), but others (the ones with graphical interfaces) do not. Would I put these above the www directory, instead of inside it? I would still need to be able to access all the files through a web browser, though.

Comment: @Nate Files which are included only by other files should go outside the doc root. Those with interfaces which you must be able to view would need some kind of authentication.

Comment: Remotely related: [What should every programmer know about web development?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development), contains some security related advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those sensitive PHP files in a directory protected by .htaccess